# Ruby spreadsheet formatting string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet, xls

In my xls file i have such row:

```
8630025500  8630025500      MOBIS/KIA/HYUNDAI   ACCENT (ТаГаз)  ЭМБЛЕМА "HYUNDAI"   2   2       1   106
```

In my code i fetch second row (8630025500) so:

```
row[1].present? ? oem = row[1] : oem = nil
```

But in db i see `863002550.0`, but why?
Why it is formatting my data? How to set data as-in-file-so-in-db?
Also i tried:

```
row[1].present? ? oem = row[1].to_s : oem = nil
```

In xls this row format is digit (also if i try to set it to common, i get the same result)...

here is example of file, if you need: [xls file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59666091/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%821.xls)

So how to import in db data, such as xls excel output do?

In db my field is varchar!

Comment: Is your DB column type a float or decimal, instead of an integer type?  That would explain it.

Comment: @bdares it is string, becouse there i could have also string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played a bit with SpreadSheet library and your file and checked the class of `row[1]`:

```
irb> sheet.each {|row| print row[1], ' ', row[1].class; puts }
866202F501 String
866201F000 String
866201G600 String
866201G800 String
8662026800.0 Float
866202H010 String
...
```

Gotcha! It chages! Some of values has type of Float, so when you call `to_s` on them (or ActiveRecord, if you don't), it adds `.0`.  That is simply the behaviour of `to_s` method of `Float`: it always adds fractional part, even if it is zero. **Database is not related here.**

Probably there might be more elegant solution (somehow configure Spreadsheet lib, modify xls) but the fastest hack is: **sees Float -> converts to int before converting to string**.

Compare:

```
irb> sheet.each {|row| puts row[1].is_a?(Numeric) ? row[1].to_i.to_s : row[1]  }
866202F501
866201F000
866201G600
866201G800
8662026800
866202H010
```

<s>So you can just add this check to your check of `.present?`, probably wrapping this into a function in order not to look so ugly.</s> Here I use `Numeric` instead of `Float`: it is base class for all numbers so in case you somehow get decimal or something else, it is also caught.

**UPD:** Here comes the code sample: you can replace your line with the following:

```
oem = row[1].is_a?(Numeric) ? row[1].to_i.to_s : row[1] if row[1].present?
```

Comment: hm... to complicated for me, how to add this to my code? something like: row[1].present?.is_a?(Numeric) ? oem = row[1].to_i.to_s : oem = nil   or what? Becouse if to_i and then to_s for example for LOL132, i will get 123, not?

Comment: Well, I mean, you have to nest your conditions.If you stick to ?: operator it will look like this:

Comment: like what? ) didnt't understand

Comment: **Sorry my internet went down :(** Well, I mean, `?:` operator inside another `?:` operator looks like mess, so you can make use of tail condition: `oem = row[1].is_a?(Numeric) ? row[1].to_i.to_s : row[1] if row[1].present?`. If row[1] not present, oem will be equal to nil because `if` body will not be executed. In case of `String` like "LOL32" `.is_a?(Number)` will return `false` so `.to_i.to_s` will not be executed, `row[1]` will. Here is the detailed version: https://gist.github.com/4596482 HTH :)

Comment: * also added snippet to the post body.

Answer (score 1):

you can save your data as varchar or string in database so that it will not change your data.
when you will fetch it you can apply conversion over there

Comment: it is string, becouse there i could have also string! In db is string type! that's the magic